# Using a Dutch Oven as a Heavy Skillet replacement

Tags: equipment, cookware, dutch-oven, skillet

I don't own a large heavy skillet - the one I do own is small and can't hold much. Is using my Dutch Oven on the stove a reasonable replacement, if I leave the lid off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing with it, but for the most part, yes.   Things like giving it a shake/toss to move things around will be more difficult, unless it's one with a long handle on one side, but you can just stir instead.   Also, lifting to pour stuff out of it will be more difficult.

Comment: I imagine effectively scraping the bottom might be a bit harder too, and forget trying to do things like pancakes.